# Restrict direct API Gateway calls unless it's from CloudFront

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, api-gateway

We created a CloudFront in front of our APIs.
Is it possible to restrict API calls other than coming from CloudFront?

**Current setup:**

Caller --> API Gateway Endpoint --> Lambda

Caller --> CloudFront Endpoint --> API Gateway Endpoint --> Lambda

**We expect to have it like this only:**

Caller --> CloudFront Endpoint --> API Gateway Endpoint --> Lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, WAF available for API gateway.
1. In CloudFront add a custom origin header
2. use WAF on API gateway and allow if request (CloudFront IP addresses + if header+value present).
CloudFront IP addresses.
http://d7uri8nf7uskq.cloudfront.net/tools/list-cloudfront-ips

Comment: Is the custom origin header necessary?

Comment: It adds more security, someone else can have his cloudfront and they can define origin as your API gateway and can make requests as cloudfront shares same ip addresses.

Comment: @JamesDean Now that WAF is integrated with API gateway, Is it still required to add a custom origin header?

Comment: It make sense to have a custom header from your cloudfront distribution to enhance the security. Think of anyone can create their own cloudfront distribution and add the origin of your APIGW endpoint. If the custom header validation does not present, that means APIGW is accessible from other cloudfront distribution created from some other aws account.