Prevent Direct API Gateway Endpoint Requests
In my AWS architecture I have a Cloudfront distribution fronting a Rest API Gateway. This is to provide the ability to completely configure the CDN.
I am concerned about the access to my default API Gateway endpoint, as this would bypass any security applied at the Cloudfront level (such as WAF).
Would implementing a custom domain name for the API Gateway and the same alternative domain name for the Cloudfront distribution prevent said potential bypass?
If this isn't sufficient, what measures are? I can't imagine that it is impossible to ensure that only Cloudfront can forward requests to an API Gateway.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181978/restrict-direct-api-gateway-calls-unless-its-from-cloudfront

Thanks for directing me there @MarkB. While it suggests a method for securing traffic, it doesn't touch on the role of a custom domain name. It's also 5 years old - is that still the recommended solution?

A custom domain name definitely doesn't solve this. Adding a custom domain name does not prevent people from going directly to the API Gateway's URL. I'm not "recommending" any solution, just pointing to a possible duplicate question.

Unfortunately API Gateway does not provide any direct way to disable the default endpoint. However you can do some steps to ensure that API Gateway only get the request from CloudFront.
1 - use API Gateway Resource policy : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html
this is an example for using it with just Cloudfront:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{region}:{account-id}:{api-id}/*/*/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::{account-id}:distribution/{distribution-id}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

2 - Configure CloudFront to send custom header like X-CloudFront to the API Gateway and configure Lambda-Authoriser or AWS WAF to validate the presence of that header, if it's there the request will be forwarded to the API Gateway, otherwise it will be rejected.

Unfortunately the resource policy method does not work. After implementing a policy like this, I was still able to interact with the Rest APIs default endpoint without the request being blocked as expected.
